# I cant find MVC 5 template on vs2017 community

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-identity

please i have a issue; two issues as a matter of fact. I will upload screen shots to better explain my ordeal.
I am new to MVC and intend to start using MVC 5. the tutorial i have works with MVC5.
I have installed vs2017 community. When i star a new project, i find the "ASP.NET Web Application" template. which i select. after giving my project a name and selecting .NET framework version, the development frameworks that shows up for MVC, WEB FORMS, WEB API all have '4' on them (meaning version 4?). see attached screen shots

when i select MVC and my project folders are scafolded, in the App_start folder, i do not find the IdentityCOnfig.cs file (see attached screen shot)

can anyone please help me with how i can rectify this? i really do not know what is going on and need your help

thanks [identityConfig.cs missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKC67.png)

[image]

[MVC template showing '4'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHt5i.png)

[image]

Comment: 1) ASP.NET 4.5 is not MVC 4. 2) You have selected **No Authentication** so that boilerplate code is not generated.

Comment: Check your _packages.config_ to verify the MVC version.

Answer (score 0):

Need choose User accounts I attached a Image

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks guys @liran thats all i really needed to know

Comment: thanks a lot @jansen. thats all i needed to know too